# Delaying render_to with Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I am trying to replicate the setup Ryan Bates has in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) on Resque, where he queues up a third party service web request and then updates his results page with results.

I am designing an application that will interact with another Rails app, ***not a browser***, and would like to replicate analogous behavior, with key difference being that **only JSON output is expected**

Currently I have something like this: (my models are `Lists` and `Tasks`, a List `has_many` Tasks and a Task `belongs_to` a List.

My `lists_controller.rb`

```
def show
  Resque.enqueue(TaskDataFetcher,params[:id])
  # confused if I need to have a render_to below this.

end
```

In `task_data_fetcher.rb`

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

  class TaskDataFetcher
    @queue = :tasks_queue

    def self.perform(id)

      list = List.new(:id => id)
      url = "taskservice.com/" + id + ".json"

      uri = URI.parse(url)
      response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
      task = Task.new(:contents => response.body)
      task.list = list
      # how to return this to the requesting server????
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Railscast you see that result doesn't automatically update after the Resque task finishes, he has to reload the page several times, re-making the `show` request.  So if you want to replicate this behaviour you could do something like:

```
def show
    list = List.find(params[:id])
    if list
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json {render :json => list.to_json}
        end
    else
        Resque.enqueue(TaskDataFetcher, params[:id])
        render :nothing => true, :status => 202
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Requerement:** 
So your user is requesting your service to see some tasks. And you have to fetch those from another service `taskservice.com`. Then i think you have to do this through database for persistency.

**Suggestion:**
You can have a model like `TaskRequest` having attributes

```
`id` # must ;)
`task_list` # might be xml or whatever format suits you best
`is_received` # boolean
```

In your `show` method,
You create a `TaskRequest` entry and render a view which will show a `loading` type thing and will be requesting for task via ajax. The ajax response should return the task list and the `is_received`. However, once you get `is_received` true with a content you should request again.

In parallel, your `TaskDataFetcher` should receive two `id`s. One that you are sending now and another is of `TaskRequest` id. So after fetching the data from the service it will store that in the `TaskRequest` table and will update the `is_recieve` to `true`. Setting it true will eventually turn off requesting for this data anymore.

well the whole explanation might seem a bit hazy. Just let me know if you didnt any part or you need anything else specifically.

*Note:* It is something like the way SO shows the code formatting while answering a question ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I mentioned this does not interact with a browser (so no ajax necessarily, unless requesting server runs JS), to do this would I need a websockets connection instead?